# How to auto-vectorise a loop which 1) modifies an array, 2) indicates whether the array changed or not at the end?

Tags: c++, c, openmp, vectorization, simd

I have this C++ function:

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef unsigned long long Word;

bool fun(Word *lhs, const Word *rhs, size_t s)
{
    bool changed = false;
    #pragma omp simd
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
        const Word old = lhs[i];
        lhs[i] |= rhs[i];
        changed = changed || old != lhs[i];
    }

    return changed;
}
```

In essence, it's a bitwise-or implementation for a bit vector (`lhs |= rhs`). I'm quite new to writing SIMD-conscious code, and I can't quite figure out how to get the compiler to vectorise this without introducing extra overhead (e.g., making `changed` an array then looping over it). Removing the `changed = ...` line allows everything to vectorise fine.

I have tried with `omp simd` and without. I don't think this is relevant but I want to keep it because `lhs` and `rhs` never overlap and I want to add the `align` clause eventually.

Currently, I'm working with GCC, but I'd like things to work well with both GCC and Clang eventually.

Comment: First off, C and C++ are 2 different languages with entirely different philosophy. Please decide which language that is before posting the question

Comment: Indeed, GCC fails to auto-vectorize this at all.  clang does, but does a very bad job (horizontal reduction *inside* the loop).  https://godbolt.org/z/vPxvrh. Note that for your current test-case, vectorization on x86 is going to require at least SSE4.1 for 64-bit compare for `==` (`pcmpeqq`), because compilers probably aren't going to be smart enough to realize that any integer element-size is fine for the overall thing.  And emulating a narrower compare probably won't look profitable.  You might have to manually vectorize with intrinsics to get asm that doesn't suck; no obvious showstopper.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31: and yet, all the mainstream compilers (that support OpenMP) have both C and C++ front-ends for the same back-end optimizer.  Best to pick one language tag for this specific question, but the answer isn't going to depend on the language you pick so this is at most a minor problem with the question.  (Unless there's a C++ STL `<algorithm>` function that happens to auto-vectorize nicely where this doesn't; seems unlikely.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks a lot. I should have mentioned I am currently working with GCC, but I'd like things to work well with both Clang and GCC eventually (updated question). SSE4.1 is fine as I'm working with CPUs from the last few years, but this is good to know. I might give manual vectorisation a shot.

Comment: The output of the Intel compiler may be relevant: https://godbolt.org/z/bG98Kz

Comment: @DanielLangr: That looks like an ICC bug!  (Or else `#pragma omp simd` without a `reduction(|:changed)` gives it license to break this code which has a serial dependency through changed, because it doesn't vectorize at all without the pragma, with that original code).  Note that it's not updating `changed` inside the SIMD loop, just doing the OR.  I think one of the scalar return paths sets a return value based on the last element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL:DR: use `Word unchanged = -1ULL;` and update it with `unchanged &= (old == lhs[i]) ? -1ULL : 0;` so this maps naturally to a SIMD compare-for-equal and SIMD AND.

Or even better, `changed |= old ^ lhs[i];` vectorizes nicely with GCC and clang, for `Word changed = 0;`.  With clang, it gives optimal asm.  With GCC, the first way is better because GCC pessimizes to `changed |= (~old) & rhs[i];  // find RHS bits that weren't already set` costing an extra movdqa register copy, or with AVX removing the ability to fold the unaligned load into a memory source for `vpor` (because it needs both operands twice, once for this and once for the main `|`).

Compare-for-unequal isn't directly available until AVX-512; doing that would have to invert the compare result before combining into a `changed` vector.

---

The overall operation can be vectorized manually with intrinsics (or asm) pretty much as written, without any major transformations, except of course optimizing to bitwise `|` OR instead of actual short-circuit evaluation.  So this is basically a missed optimization.  **But in the natural asm implementation of this, your vector of `changed` elements would be the same width as the data, not just 4 `bool`s.**  (For x86 that would take an extra `vmovmskpd` to feed a scalar `or` instead of just a SIMD `vpor`, and most ISAs don't have a movemask operation so maybe the generic vectorizer isn't even considering using it.  Fun fact: clang auto-vectorizes your original code really badly, doing a horizontal OR down to a scalar `bool` every iteration.)

**Using `Word changed = 0;` lets this vectorize fairly decently**, with `changed |= ...`, with or without OpenMP pragmas (differently, haven't sorted out which is actually better for every combo).  Compilers are dumb (complex pieces of machinery, not human understanding) and often don't figure out things like this for themselves - auto-vectorization is hard enough that they sometimes need some hand-holding.

So the trick is making `changed` the same width as the array elements.

---

If you use OpenMP, **you need to tell the OpenMP vectorizer about reductions** such as sum of an array with `+`, or in this case OR.  In this case, `#pragma omp simd reduction(|:changed)`.  You should be using `changed |= stuff` instead of logical short-circuit eval anyway, if you want this to vectorize into branchless SIMD.  `reduction(|:changed)` actually seems to override your actual code to some degree, so be careful it matches.

ICC even breaks your code (not updating changed in the SIMD part) if you just use `#pragma omp simd` https://godbolt.org/z/bG98Kz. (Perhaps that gives it license to ignore serial dependencies, or at least reductions, which you didn't tell it about?  Either that or an ICC bug, I don't know OpenMP very well.)

---

With the original `bool changed` instead of `Word`, GCC doesn't auto-vectorize at all, and clang does a nasty job (horizontal reduction to a scalar `bool` inside the inner loop!)

---

### Two versions that auto-vectorize:

[**On Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOQCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIRmzyAZ2ydURAg2rZ6mAMLp2AVwC29EAE5yOzABkC9bADlTAI2ykQ0/gAd0S4k16A2MzS3I/AI0Ge0cXE3dPb2VVbHUgpiJWUiIQ03MrFTVo%2BkzsoljnNw8vfiUsnLywwoaKhyqEmu8ASmV0I1JULgByGQBmB1RjHABqSTG9eswcGgA6JHncSQAGAEEd3aIATx9sFZmjegDgR0wZ9gZge8eZgHUyTHn5PYPXdEMZjRLgB9ABu0gg71IdwAVOwkEpyDMMFciG8PjMYaQEUiAgAvbDAtFKboHSQAdm%2BuxmNPR0Iu9FQSDEwDOczGABEZgBabgAVVsti%2BBwA9CLkaJxIDWAR2EoZiQZqC0iRSAQCfMAGJgMBamkAcT0ehmAHcyABreWseXYAAep3UbJNxCQIudRCQ/TRPlIrGAJlYB1pc2kYx9foDM3QJh8MwCJjupDORnSDAgMgAbCBLkyWWdSXtg3RSDMIPjCWiCOyudsvjMq/NjUo6woFARunNKUHg7SUfU6XdDHd5lz4c2AKyyAiSccc4WFns0sczqczrkUvQjmbYier2fz6mLhm58RszNbiBD6tb5eT6ezjt63kC2wzEAzWtjKnBilzhc0pMiAGegZh1HNmVPT4vzJck/32PY/gBIF6DBbhIQxOEcWRBh%2ByhWEd1xdUKzjAt9i7f8B2RCDWWHTkPwPH9Q3Df1WCjGM4wIBNt2TVN6HTck9DQaj8xpMUox8EoOFxaNsBma0TBmQgaBoDwdCGeV3VdTSvW7Gli1LcsiXrat6K/YzGzjFs5DbR9yMPRc%2BzRPCo3YWjRwRFd7znaCKODE8aM7Tc6IgAA/IdH2kDNtw8u81zrUTxRoBw7gAJQACSYGZXGIeUPVYNETVU%2BgwGGNEOCTVhMCOONsCIVYZh8AZZOyohnRUJF6HQGYM14bkWu5VITB0NEmAASQAWXXTkt0cM4zlWXSe1vPd1wErcd08uKfPsnsxX8s81uCq8dRvGKVsfMZNR5flBTfUzZGDMSkwARyMAgk3lBxlRyBwng9WTUBjbBnu4pQjHYIgkVcIw0TYEC6FcuSZiGkwyGq9BTl9XRTRdGZdgANQADQZdgCHNWT/qy4g2tk76AgYMlfNpPbhLcqi82HNaBNLY7dTo5avNJMzmfFJRPRyZF3tQN60WwUEOHrDTsHeu59LGyakQwGNZWwT7HGUghUAIYb2COBaKN/RmdsA4D2cgg9f2GXp2BAYZx2GchzGGbYPfQV3N2suQ436QZZPGbgPaIV2fe6XpzRAcdyVWcdE7GMZuB68kLF4ckc5EV3eA9kwE%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%2B087SXzvusygjB75n0fs/V%2BWARjFM/pxdZf8GDMDYPvEBQhh590gYHRQj94FZJKRJIIKC0EYOyEyEcuCgEEKIZcbApDyGUNkswjGOh2LchoewOhuKGG%2Bg4cUII3D9BqLCPw3QJjhHD1ESUQxEQpElFpTUBRnCSjaKZZorlxj2hCPZcoAxlK%2BHCvKGysxfQBhWO4NkuxXSSmuxcW4jxwBUCoG8X46QgTCCqlCcPGYESRkeANXEqBshelVPIPHXg0hVi8DtRmDMzixjjmkNsd144xhtNycXQehTp6lOUOUypTtsnSE6UGyuFTkm9DpmS3gQA%3D%3D%3D) with `-O3 -march=nehalem -mtune=skylake -fopenmp` (So using SSE4.1 / 4.2, but not AVX or BMI1/BMI2).  I haven't looked in detail at which ends up with less clunky cleanup code.

```
#include <stddef.h>
typedef unsigned long long Word;

bool fun_v1(Word *lhs, const Word *rhs, size_t s)
{
    Word changed = 0;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(|:changed)  // optional, some asm differences with/without
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
        const Word old = lhs[i];
        changed |= (~old) & rhs[i];   // find RHS bits that weren't already set. pure bitwise, no 64-bit-element SIMD == needed.  Do this before storing so compiler doesn't have to worry about lhs/rhs overlap.
        lhs[i] |= rhs[i];
        //changed |= (old != lhs[i]) ? -1ULL : 0;    // requires inverting the cmpeq result, but can fold a memory operand with AVX unlike the bitwise version

        //changed = changed || (old != lhs[i]);    // short circuit eval is weird for SIMD, compiles inefficiently.
    }

    return changed;
}
```

(**update: `changed |= old ^ lhs[i];` appears even better** to get a non-zero value on not-equal.  It uses only commutative operations, and doesn't need `==` / pcmpeqq.  @chtz suggested this in comments, I haven't rewritten the rest of the answer to cut out discussion of worse optoins.   clang will auto-vectorize with it, and with AVX allows a memory source operand for rhs because it's only needed once. https://godbolt.org/z/ex5519. So this appears to be the best of both worlds.)

`changed |= (old != lhs[i]) ? -1ULL : 0;` is also still only 10 instructions (9 uops) in the inner loop, same as `changed |= (~old) & rhs[i];`, for GCC 10.2 without AVX.  But for clang, that defeats auto-vectorization!  Clang will handle `changed |= (old != lhs[i]);`  (or with an explicit `? 1 : 0`) so that's odd.  `-1ULL` avoids needing a `set1_epi64x(1)` vector constant so I used that.

Versions using `==` or `!=` will need SSE4.1 `pcmpeqq` for vectorization of 64-bit compare for `==`:  compilers probably aren't going to be smart enough to realize that any integer element-size is fine for the overall thing.  And emulating a narrower compare probably won't look profitable.

The `~old & rhs[i]` way works with just SSE2.  Ending the loop with SSE4.1 `ptest` instead of shuffles and POR and MOVQ would be more efficient, but compilers are pretty dumb about stuff like that.  (And handling the ends of loops in general.
Just naive reduction, and scalar cleanup for odd elements instead of a possibly-overlapping final vector that ends at the end of the arrays.  `|=` is idempotent so at worst it would cause a store-forwarding stall if you don't schedule your loads well.  That's another thing you could do better with manual vectorization, but using intrinsics would force one SIMD vector width, while auto-vec lets the compiler use wider vectors when you compile for an AVX2 CPU like `-march=haswell` or `-march=znver2`.)

---

**Until AVX-512, only compare for `==` is available** (or `>`), not `!=` directly.  To reduce that the way we want, we'd need to `unchanged &= (old == updated);`.  This lets GCC save 1 instruction in the loop, bringing it down to 9 instructions, 8 uops.  It can possibly run at 1 iteration per 2 cycles.

But clang for some reason doesn't auto-vectorize it at all.  Apparently clang doesn't like the `? -1 : 0` ternary here or in the other version, maybe not realizing that's what SIMD compares produce.

```
bool fun_v2(Word *lhs, const Word *rhs, size_t s)
{
    Word unchanged = -1ULL;
// clang fails to vectorize?!?  GCC works as expected with/without pragma
    #pragma omp simd reduction(&:unchanged)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
        const Word old = lhs[i];
        lhs[i] |= rhs[i];
        unchanged &= (old == lhs[i]) ? -1ULL : 0;
    }
    return !unchanged;
}
```

With AVX available, `vpor` with a memory source operand would be efficient if compilers weren't using a stupid indexed addressing mode, forcing it to un-laminate on Intel Sandybridge family (but not on AMD).

---

Note that if you're thinking of using `Word` as a wide type to use this on arbitrary data of other types, **beware strict-aliasing rules and Undefined Behaviour**.  Manual vectorization might be a good bet because `_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128*)int_ptr);` is fully strict-aliasing safe: vector pointers (and load / store intrinsics) are like `char*` in that they can alias anything.  For a portable version, either use memcpy or GNU C `typedef unsigned long unaligned_aliasing_chunk __attribute__((may_alias,aligned(1)))`.  "Word" has different meanings in asm for different ISAs, like being 16-bit in x86, so it's not the best name for a type you want to be was wide as the machine can efficiently use.  `unsigned long` is often that, but is 32-bit on some 64-bit machines.  `unsigned long long` is probably fine.

Comment: Thank you! Extremely helpful, solves my problem and I learnt a lot. Two small follow-ups: 1) what do you mean by "`reduction(|:changed)` actually seems to override your actual code to some degree, so be careful it matches."? And 2) what would be a more descriptive or idiomatic type name than `Word`?

Comment: 1) try using `reduction(&:changed)` instead, and see that the compiler seems to use `PAND` instead of `POR`, at least for the vectorized parts.  There doesn't seem to be any checking to make sure it matches the actual scalar logic!  2) `chunktype` or `chunkt` is pretty neutral; for big-integer stuff (if the array represents a single large integer), `limb` (or a typename like `limbt` maybe) is used in some libraries, like GMP.  Unfortunately names of the form `xxx_t` are reserved for future use by ISO C and C++ so it's recommended not to use that pattern for custom types. :/

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll go with some variation of Chunk I think.

Comment: @mbarbar: Actually, correction, `reduction(&:changed)` just optimizes away the update because the initial value of `0`, and `0 & x == 0`, means the result is definitely 0.  But anyway, as I mentioned in the next paragraph, without any `reduction` clause, ICC at least seems to have also optimized away the `changed` logic when compiling your original.  That may be a bug, or it may be allowed by OpenMP.  There's no real need to use OpenMP, but it may help hint the compiler that this loop is Important. For GCC it seems to make the after-loop reduction dumber, although store/reload isn't much worse

Comment: Small alternative for "v1": `const Word old = lhs[i]; lhs[i] |= rhs[i]; changed |= old ^ lhs[i];` can save one register-register copy for pre-AVX code (although GCC seems to refactor it to your way again).

Comment: @chtz: Oh good idea, that's a good way to get non-zero on not-equal using only commutative operations.  It auto-vectorizes very nicely with clang, and it's nearly a best of both worlds with GCC.